# Easiest way to design feedback for boost converter

Tags: boost

I'm trying to design a feedback for a boost converter. When I research on the internet all I get is some really complex control system type stuff that I dont really understand or maybe too advanced for me. I'm not too interested in making it perfect or respond immediately to changes but just a basic feedback.

From what I understand, I need an error op amp with a reference being my desired output voltage which is 30V. I also need a ramp and this ramp is compared with the error and hence generating the square wave.

So how would I set my peak ramp voltage ?, I'm guessing it has to be higher than my reference because at startup the error would be 30-0 = 30V and if the peak is 30V on the ramp then the switch would be constantly on.

I also saw another way using a 555 timer but not sure how that would work

I was currently trying to use a micro-controller with adc as I thought or still think it would be the easiest way. The problem is the output voltage just kept oscillating when I compared the adc result with 30V. Maybe the changes weren't  sensitive enough ?

What do you guys think ?

Comment: In order to design a boost converter you need to understand power electronics and the necessary control theory.  There's a right half plane zero that makes them difficult to compensate, a maximum duty cycle limitation, and the potential for voltage runaway under certain conditions.  You're better off buying a boost converter or at least getting a boost converter IC with a reference circuit from one of the semiconductor vendors.  If this is a learning exercise go figure out all that stuff you don't understand before you build hardware.

Comment: You can not simply use a ramp for this kind of circuit. If there is no load your convertor should pretty much go to zero pulse width since all you need to do it top up the capacitor. When there is a heavy load you need more width. As such, the error you measure at the output is used to SLEW the pulse width either up or down. It should settle at the right level for the current load. It is complicated.

Comment: Even when you use a boost converter IC (or any other configuration for that matter) things are not simple at all. From the late great master of this (Jim Williams) - http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an25fa.pdf

Comment: I got an interesting discussion about almost the same topic ( you are not creating a buck , but the concepts are similar I think ) http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/292172/11079 don't expect is easy to wire your own switching converter...

Comment: I would recommend you design it at first in a pSpice simulator and test it to get your desired output.
The second step is to go in some Semiconductor vendor website and buy the components,Fairchild, Texsas Instrument have those IC:s you need